# Swedish dictionary using Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, dictionaries

I'm going to write a paper in Swedish together with my fellow students with the help of Overleaf. I now wonder if there are a package that has a Swedish dictionary that I can use as spellcheck?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a LaTeX package (at least, I'm unaware of LaTeX packages that actually perform spell-checking!), but Overleaf has a Swedish spell-checker. If you click on the Overleaf project settings icon (i.e. the gear icon on the upper right of the Overleaf editor, just next to your username), you should be able to see Svenska in the list of spell-check languages.